# How to do Validation using "name = xxx"

Tags: javascript, calculator

How to do Validation using "name"

Here is Loan auto calc script.

https://jsfiddle.net/diessses/Lpaqnoue/

I have a question about Validation.
I could error check using "id = xxx". but I changed code as "name = xxx".
Could you teach me how to write code using "name = xxx" please?

```
function showError(error) {
  document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
  const errorDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const card = document.querySelector('.card');
  const heading = document.querySelector('.heading');
  errorDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';
  card.insertBefore(errorDiv, heading);
  setTimeout(clearError, 300);
}
```

And also I would like to do validation at "cb_amount" Input field.

'cb_amount' value must like this

'cb_amount' =< ('amount' - 'downpayment') / 2

I would like to add this at showError function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getElementsByName to get the element.

```
let downpayment = documnet.getElementsByName("downpayment")[0].value
let amount = document.getElementsByName("amount")[0].value
let cb_amount = document.getElementsByName("cb_amount")[0].value
```

now you can write your condition.
Here the value returned by documnet.getElementsByName("downpayment") is array like element so we need to use [0] to fetch the required element.